# Set format of getElementbyid("Upfront_fee").value to a decimal(10500.00) monitory value

Tags: javascript, html, input, getelementbyid

I am trying to display the value of a input type text for both Upfront_fee and Additional_fee to a Monitory values with 2 decimals.
Neither to.Fixed or parseFloat seems to work here.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function check() {
       parseFloat(document.getElementById("Upfront_fee").value = 10500);
       parseFloat(document.getElementById("Additional_fee").value = (document.getElementById("Practice_Qty").value-1)*1266);
       }
       function setDecimal() {
        this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
       }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table>
    <th colspan="4">Quotation Values</th>
    <tr><td><label>Practice Numbers:</label></td><td colspan="3"><input type="number" name="Practice_Qty" id="Practice_Qty"  min="1" onChange="check();"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Service Providers:</label></td><td colspan="3"><input type="number" name="Providers_Qty" id="Providers_Qty"  min="1" onChange="check();"></td></tr>
    </table>
    <hr></hr>
    <table>
    <tr><th colspan="2">Upfront Pricing</th></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Upfront fee</label></td><td><input type="Number" name="Upfront_fee" id="Upfront_fee" min="0.00" max="99999.99"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><label>Additional Directory upfront fee</label></td><td><input type="text" name="Additional_fee" id="Additional_fee"></td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are not calling `setDecimal` anywhere ...

Comment: do not work Value in my text box still displays as 10500

Comment: setDecimal was an attempt to apply toFixed(2) or parseFloat in a seperate function other than what @zer00ne is suggesting which does not work.

Comment: You're calling parseFloat the wrong way. In the first line of check(), you set the value to 10500 and then call parseFloat, but that doesn't do anything, since you discard the result.

Comment: @MrLister so what would be the correct wat to call parseFloat then ?

Comment: @KurtHectic Do something with the result. Like you do in setDecimal(). That is what the parseFloat function does: it takes an input and returns a value.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `var dec = parseFloat(document.getElementById("Upfront_fee").value).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are just assigning the value `10500` in the `check` function. Instead, you should assign the value after parsing it and then fixing it to `2 decimal places` like this.

```js
function check(){
  document.getElementById('box').value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('box').value).toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<input id="box" type="number" name="Practice_Qty" id="Practice_Qty"  min="1" onChange="check();">
```

Note: Run the snippet, change the value in the textbox and see the result

Just like you are doing in `setDecimal` function but you are using `this` which is not pointing to your DOM element I guess. Use it like this

```
document.getElementById('your input id').value = parseFloat('your value').toFixed(2)
```